# How to remove a outliers with z-scores (3 or -3) using apply function

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-cleaning

I was working on UCI heart disease, and changed all the measurable values into z scores, and I want replace the values which are greater than 3 or smaller than -3 with 3 and 3 respectively or with mean.

My sample code is:

```
> import pandas as pd import numpy as np
> 
> df= pd.DataFrame({'X': np.random.randn(10),
>                   'Y': np.random.randn(10)})
> 
> df=df.append(pd.DataFrame({'X':np.array([3,-3,3.3,4]),
>                                     'Y':np.array([-3.4,2,1,5])}),ignore_index=True)
> 
> df['X'].apply(lambda x: x=3 if x>3 else (x = -3 if x<-3 else x))
```

But I'm receiving the following error:

```
File "<ipython-input-144-8d678556d1e7>", line 1
    df['X'].apply(lambda x: x=3 if x>3 else (x= -3 if x<-3 else x))
                                              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: You have a syntax error in the lambda, it has nothing to do with pandas or Z-scores. Can you try to just assign that lambda expression to a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `lambda` syntax is such that after `x:`, you just state the function value, without repeating the `x` (except for the conditions in this case).

```py
df['X'].apply(lambda x: 3 if x > 3 else (-3 if x < -3 else x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try with [Series.clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas-series-clip) instead:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X': np.array([3, -3, 3.3, 4]),
     'Y': np.array([-3.4, 2, 1, 5])}
)

df['X'] = df['X'].clip(lower=-3, upper=3)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     X    Y
0  3.0 -3.4
1 -3.0  2.0
2  3.0  1.0
3  3.0  5.0
```

---

Or [DataFrame.clip](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.clip.html#pandas-dataframe-clip) to apply to whole frame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'X': np.array([3, -3, 3.3, 4]),
     'Y': np.array([-3.4, 2, 1, 5])}
)

df = df.clip(lower=-3, upper=3)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     X    Y
0  3.0 -3.0
1 -3.0  2.0
2  3.0  1.0
3  3.0  3.0
```